# Choosing a best solution available with azure for a video processing scenario

Tags: azure, azure-batch, azure-container-instances

Here is the scenario for which I am developing a app.

User submits a request to server. And immediately I need to stitch together some video clips and apply some filters and send it back to user immediately (its taking around 16 seconds in my desktop with 8 core system). Since video processing takes 100% of the CPU each need to be processed in its own instance. There may be more than 1000 users at peak time. I can't go with a queuing system since the video needs to processed as fast as possible and sent back to user. So this needs to run parallel.

I am exploring Container Instances and Batch Service. But I am not sure which would be the perfect fit for this scenario. Media Services is ruled out since we are applying some custom filters and other things. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Without knowing a lot about your code, you could look into Azure Functions.  These automatically scale up on depend but I am not sure you will get the performance you need from them.

Comment: Azure Functions definitely not going to work. As the process require more CPU cores. Regarding code think of it as running ffmpeg which processes the video and generates a output video file.

Comment: Container Instances seems to have similar capabilities of Azure Functions with higher capacity. But still there seems to be a restriction in number of vCPUs and number of parallel processes.